# Direct to appropriate ViewController when user logs out/ is not logged in

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-login, logout, swrevealviewcontroller

I posted a similar question some time back, but it turns out the solution I chose is not sustainable nor a good one. So I'm trying again, with a different approach.

**Here's my problem**

I'm making an app that uses Facebook login *and* connects to a server. Therefore, at any given time, the user has to be logged in with Facebook and the user_id needs to be stored in the `NSUserDefaults`. If at any time in the app, any of the two is not present, I need to direct the user to a log-in screen.

In the same fashion, if the user manually presses log out, I need to direct him/ her to that same screen.

Seing that I'm using the `SWRevealViewController`, I need more than one `UINavigationController`. Therefore the `popViewController` does not work.

**Here's my app setup**

The `initialViewController` is a `UINavigationController`, pointing to another `ViewController`. In here, I check if the user is signed into Facebook and that the user_id is stored in the `NSUserDefaults`. If they are, I direct them to the `SWRevealViewController`. If they are not, I direct them to a `LoginViewController` (I use `performSegueWithIdentifier:`). From the `LoginViewController`, after the user is successfully signed into both Facebook and my servers, I direct them to the same `SWRevealViewController`.

Basically, the `SWRevealViewController` splits into two: A `sw_front` and a `sw_rear` (the menu). Each of those requires their own `UINavigationController` (as far as I know, I didn't get it to work without).

From here on, the app splits into several different `ViewControllers`.

You can see the storyboard in this image:
[image: Image 1]
[(Link to full-res image here)](http://bildr.no/image/SXFxaWV1.jpeg)
(The logout button is the blue one on the top, the login is the blue one at the start)

**Here's what I've tried:**

The last time I asked a similar question, I chose to go with a solution where I present the `InitialNavigationController` using the `presentViewController` function when the user logs out. This seemed to work fine, and the new `ViewController` was presented `modally` which other apps seem to do as well (see linkedIn and more).

However, when I proceeded to log in again, the Facebook `showLoggedInUser` method seemed to be called twice (I placed a `NSLog()` statement in there). When I repeated a third time, it ran three times. Fourth login, four times, and so on.

In addition, on the second logout, I would get a warning in the compiler saying **`Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x13c566730> on <UINavigationController: 0x13c549c70> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`**. This warning would also keep incrementing as I repeated the login-logout process.

**What I want:**

As I understand, I keep adding the `InitialViewController` to the stack as a modal view, and this is not what I want. I simply want to go back to the start. Or anything that works for that matter. Just as long as I have a simple login/ logout system that works, I'll be glad. Bear in mind that we need to be able to call the View that should be presented from any view in the app if the user appears to be logged out (if he logged out from Facebook, if the Facebook thing timed out, or if the `NSUserDefaults` for some reason reset (for example under an update)).

If possible, I'd like to know what other apps does to achieve this (for example linkedIn, Facebook, Twitter, or anyone else).

What I've been thinking about is adding a separate `LoginView` not connected to anything, that I can load up modally whenever I see the user is logged out. Whenever the login is completed, I simply dismiss the view and the user returns to where he was last.

The only problem I see about this is that when the user logs out, he is technically still "inside" the app, though he cannot dismiss the modal view controller without logging in.

Would this be a bearable solution to my problem?

What do you suggest?

Some physical code showing how to present the new view/ going back (or any other solution) is preferred, but any help is appreciated!

---

I know this was a long question, and there are possibly many answers, but I've been stuck at this for way to long and I just want a solution that will work with my setup. So I felt the need to explain everything. If there's anything you don't get, please don't hesitate to ask!

Thank you so much in advance!